# GSON exception during parsing timestamp

Tags: android, timestamp, gson

My application can't parse REST API response because of timestamp format. REST API returns JSON:

```
   {
        "id": 4,
        "username": "test555",
        "email": "test555@test.com",
        "password": "pass",
        "role": "USER",
        "enabled": 1,
        "lastPassChange": null,
        "created": [2019, 6, 16, 19, 8, 34, 843438000]
    }
```

But my application throws exception because it was expecting object but it receives array.

I added implementation 
    `'com.fatboyindustrial.gson-jodatime-serialisers:gson-jodatime-serialisers:1.7.0'`

and added to my gson singleton:

```
public class GsonSingleton {
    private static GsonSingleton sInstace;
    private Gson gson;

    public static synchronized GsonSingleton getInstance(){
        if(sInstace == null){
            sInstace = new GsonSingleton();
        }
        return sInstace;
    }

    private GsonSingleton(){
        this.gson = Converters.registerLocalDateTime(new GsonBuilder()).create();
    }

    public Gson gson(){
        return this.gson;
    }

    public JSONObject obj2Json(Object o) throws JSONException{
        return new JSONObject(gson.toJson(o));
    }
}
```

but it do not help.

Line where exceptions occurs:

```
User savedUser = GsonSingleton.getInstance().gson().fromJson(response.toString(), User.class);
```

Exception stack:

```
`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 191 path $.created
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
    at eu.blubit.autobook.view.AccountFormActivity$1.onResponse(AccountFormActivity.java:153)
    at eu.blubit.autobook.view.AccountFormActivity$1.onResponse(AccountFormActivity.java:148)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:90)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 191 path $.created
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:215)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131) 
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222) 
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927) 
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892) 
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841) 
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813) 
    at eu.blubit.autobook.view.AccountFormActivity$1.onResponse(AccountFormActivity.java:153) 
    at eu.blubit.autobook.view.AccountFormActivity$1.onResponse(AccountFormActivity.java:148) 
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:90) 
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1563) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1451)`
```

But I should receive User.class object:

```
@Entity
public class User {

@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
private Long id;

@Size(min=3, max=20)
private String username;

private String email;

@Size(min=6)
private String password;

private String role;

private Integer enabled;

private LocalDateTime lastPassChange;

private LocalDateTime created;
//setters and getters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found other way which works for me. 
I added new class to my singleton which is custom deserializer for json.

```
public class JsonDateTimeArrayDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime>{
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonArray jArr = json.getAsJsonArray();
        return LocalDateTime.of(jArr.get(0).getAsInt(), jArr.get(1).getAsInt(), jArr.get(2).getAsInt(), jArr.get(3).getAsInt(), jArr.get(4).getAsInt(), jArr.get(5).getAsInt(), jArr.get(6).getAsInt());
    }
}
```

And I had to register it in `private GsonSingleton()`:

```
this.gson = new GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(LocalDateTime.class, new JsonDateTimeArrayDeserializer()).create
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as Converter:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("[YYYY,  MM, dd, HH, mm, ss, SSSSSSSSS]").create();
Converters.registerLocalDateTime(gson).create();
```

Comment: No, it don't work. I got type mismatch in registerLocalDateTime. So I changed to: `GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("[YYYY,  MM, dd, HH, mm, ss, SSSSSSSSS]"); this.gson = Converts.registerLocalDateTime(gb).create();` but it also don't work. Parsing json throws same exception.